# Get path of file from External Storage in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I am trying to get the path of the file which the user selects using the default file viewer.

I have a button inside a fragment and want to set its onClickListener to get the path of that file.

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.openfile,container,false);
    Button choseFile = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_chose_file);
    final EditText et1 = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.opened_file);
    choseFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("file/*");
            getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE) ;
        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
                        et1.setText(FilePath);
                        Log.e("activity", "onActivityResult: ");
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }

    });
    return rootView;
}
```

but onActivityResult never gets called and log remains empty. Also, I am unable to select a file.

**Screenshot of emulator**

[image: Screenshot of emulator]

onClick on ids.txt does nothing.

Comment: if u using android 6.0 than you need to runtime permission or set the permission to Mainfiest to for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to get path of file which user selects using default file viewer.

Android does not have a "default file viewer". You are using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` with an invalid MIME type (as there is no official MIME type beginning with `file/`). I would expect your code to fail on most devices.

> but onActivityResult never gets called and log remains empty ,also I am unable to select a file

First, only once you tap a file would that activity trigger `onActivityResult()` with a `RESULT_OK` response.

Second, if you want the *fragment's* `onActivityResult()` to be called, then call `startActivityForResult()` *on the fragment*. You are calling `startActivityForResult()` on the activity, so the activity' `onActivityResult()` is being called.

> onClick on ids.txt does nothing.

Try a valid MIME wildcard MIME type (e.g., `text/*`, `*/*`) and see if you have better results.

Also, get rid of `String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();` and [use the `Uri` properly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html), please. Activities implementing `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` do not have to return a `file:` `Uri`. In fact, going forward, that will become very uncommon, as [Android N is starting to ban the `file:` `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html).